# xquery Failed to load http://expath.org/ns/http-client

Tags: linux, import, module, xquery, xml-namespaces

Failed to load namespace http://expath.org/ns/http-client for xquery documentation:

```
java -ea -cp ./saxon9.jar net.sf.saxon.Query -mr:"http://expath.org/ns/http-client" -q:'tester.xq'
```

code to send request in tester.xq:

```
let $request :=
<http:request href='http://localhost:8080/domestic-test'
method='post'>
<http:multipart media-type='multipart/form-data' boundary='--A0Bce'>
<http:body media-type='application/xml'>
<query xmlns="http://basex.org/rest">
  <text><![CDATA[
    <html>{
      for $i in 1 to 3
      return <div>Section {$i }</div>
    }</html>
  ]]></text>
</query>
</http:body>
</http:multipart>
</http:request>
return http:send-request($request)
```

How to import module using command line linux to run xquery file ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saxon has no built-in support for EXPath's HTTP-Client extension, but can be installed as extension packages. [IBM describes how to do this for XSLT](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-expath/#xslt_example), but the instructions should also work for XQuery.

> To install the client, perform the following steps:
>
> - Download the [EXPath Packaging module for SAXON](http://code.google.com/p/expath-pkg/downloads/list).
> - Download the [EXPath HTTP Client module for SAXON](http://code.google.com/p/expath-http-client/downloads/list).
> - Install the EXPath Packaging module (follow the README file).
> - Using the EXPath Packaging module, deploy the EXPath HTTP Client XAR package.

Then declare the `http` namespace accordingly:

```
declare namespace http = "http://expath.org/ns/http-client";
```

Given [the example in the implementation](https://github.com/adamretter/expath-http-client-java/blob/master/samples/saxon.xq) you might have to declare and use another namespace.

Comment: That is work but there is error in content-length
I receive the request using java, and request.content-length = -1.
but I print the content ???
why content-length is wrong ???
Thanks